# SSH-Agent writing unencrypted keys to swap memory

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, openssh

I have recently set up a computer with full disk encryption, and I decided not to encrypt the swap partition for performance reasons. I have been using ssh-agent on another computer to load my private keys, and was wondering if it were possible that the unencrypted keys got written to swap memory, hence risking having my private keys being unencrypted at rest.

OpenSSH version:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_9.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
```

Comment: I think you meant to put your OpenSSH version in there, not OpenSSL.

Comment: There's a good chance your encryption key will end up in swap as well. I would *not* trust such a setup, and consider the ssh keys the least of my worries.

Comment: [The code is accessible over GitHub](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh-agent.c). From what I can tell, OpenSSH (including `ssh-agent`) uses plain old `malloc` on Linux without any attempt to prevent swapping through functions like `mlock`.

Answer (score 4):

Full-system encryption is basically useless with unencrypted swap. There are ways for a program to deny swapping of its memory, but it's unreliable. All sorts of secrets could end up being swapped. The only solution to your concern is to wipe and encrypt the swap. Modern processors do AES in hardware so it's unlikely to cause performance issues.